# JavaScript - different action to same input type but different name

Tags: javascript, input, submit, action

I have a problem with my js script because for both button will open te same site 1. I don't know why?

Could somebody help me to resolve this problem?

```js
$('#trackAndTraceForm').submit(function(event) {
  var val = $('input[name="numer"]', this).val();
  elementClicked = $(event.target);
  var typeBtn = elementClicked.attr('name');

  if (typeBtn == 'spr') {


    if (val.substring(0, 1) != '0') {
      //console.log('nie zero');
      var action = 'http://92.43.115.24:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx';
      $(this).attr('action', action);
    } else {
      var action = 'http://apollo.loxx.pl:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx';
      $(this).attr('action', action);
    }
  } else if (typeBtn == 'pod') {
    var action = 'http://www.loxx.pl/loxx_it/loxxwarpod.php';
    $(this).attr('action', action);
  } else {
    //do nothing;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="trackAndTraceForm" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="get" action="http://apollo.loxx.pl:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx">
  <span>Track and Trace:</span>
  <input type="text" value="" name="numer" placeholder="Numer listu przewozowego" />
  <input type="submit" name="spr" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Sprawdz" />
  <input type="submit" name="pod" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="POD" />
</form>
```

If I click POD button action is the same like for Sprawdz with url

```
http://apollo.loxx.pl:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx?numer=0317037128&pod=POD
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to prevent the original event from triggering the default submit action. You do that by calling `event.preventDefault();`.</strike>

Here's what your code needs to look like:

```
$('#trackAndTraceForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // <-- the important bit
  // ...

  if (typeBtn == 'spr') {
    // ...
  } else if (typeBtn == 'pod') {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Looks like you can't change the `action` attribute of the event after the submit event has been called.

What you need to do is to add event listeners to each of your buttons, change the `action` attribute and then submit the form:

```
function changeFormAction(newAction) {
  $('#trackAndTraceForm').attr('action', newAction);
}
$('input[name="spr"]')
  .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('input[name="numer"]').val();
    var newAction = value.startsWith('0') ? 
      'http://apollo.loxx.pl:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx' :     'http://92.43.115.24:8080/ApolloWebBooking/WebBooking/StatusyPrzesylki.aspx';

    changeFormAction(newAction);
    $('#trackAndTraceForm').submit();
}
$('input[name="pod"]')
  .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeFormAction('http://www.loxx.pl/loxx_it/loxxwarpod.php');
    $('#trackAndTraceForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but If I added event.preventDefault(); then when I click any button (spr or pod) there is now action for both. script not redirect for url.

Comment: Updated my answer with a different approach. A bit more work, but should work as requested.